# Completion closure within a closure

Tags: swift

Just starting to learn Swift coming from Obj-C - this is something simple I'm not understanding:

```
 class func queryForAllUsersWithCallback(completion: (users :[User]?, error :NSError?) ->()) {

        var query = PFQuery(className:User.parseClassName())
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
            (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) in

            completion(users: objects, error: error);
        })
    }
```

Give me a compiler error:

```
 Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '(([AnyObject]?, NSError?) -> _)'
```

If I comment out the line:

```
 completion(users: objects, error: error);
```

the error goes away, so the warning is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`completion` takes as its first argument an array of `User`, whereas `objects` is an array of `AnyObject`.  There’s no guarantee what is in `objects` is of the correct type (could be a motley collection of various types for all the compiler knows) so it won’t compile.

If you do a conditional cast it should compile, i.e.:

```
 completion(users: objects as? [User], error: error)
```

Note, this will check at runtime that every element in `objects` really is of the correct type.  If any of them aren’t, the whole array will be `nil` when passed to the completion handler.  This will compile, since the argument is optional, but might be quite surprising/fail silently or even worse, crash because somewhere inside `completion` might be the assumption it *isn’t* nil, so it could get force-unwrapped.

So you might instead want to put some error handling in:

```
if let users = objects as? [User] {
    completion(users: users, error: error)
}
else {
    // log or fatalError or something
}
```

(apologies if the syntax of some of the above isn’t quite right, I haven’t tested the code since your snippet isn’t reproducible/stand-alone)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast the objects to User as:

```
 completion(users: objects as? [User], error: error)
```